# Shell Command - Bring to front

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that runs a shell command to do a constant ping, but when its ran, it does not bring the cmd window to front.

This seems like it has to have some little fix I am missing.

**Code:**

```
Shell("ping " & IPAddy.Text & " -t")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shell("ping " & IPAddy.Text & " -t", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

Use the Style parameter with the argument AppWinStyle.NormalFocus as shown above

MSDN: Shell Function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx