# VBA command line object requesting login, waiting for user input

Tags: vba, cmd, ms-word, filesystemobject

I wrote a script that obtains some information from a program through a command line prompt.
Obtaining the information works as long as you are logged into the program I'm trying to extract the information from.

This is how I'm connecting to the program:

```
Set Appl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe im connect")
```

Returning (if you're not logged in):
(please note: this is the theoretical output if I manually type the command into a command window)

```
Connecting to <some server or another>...
Authentication failed for <user: me> on <some server or another>
Enter password for <user: me> on <some server or another> (*****):
```

And this is where my macro gets stuck.

I've tried checking for the return string "Enter password", but since the file system object calling the shell gets stuck waiting for the user input I'm not able to really do anything about it.

So all of this is not working:

```
Set ApplOutput = Appl.StdOut
While Not ApplOutput.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = ApplOutput.ReadLine
    If Left(sLine, 14) = "Enter password" Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR!!" & vbCrLf & "Please login to the Integrity Client") 
    End If
Wend
```

Is there any way to check if the command window is waiting for a user input (as in the case above) and if so bring the command window to the front and ask the user to input their password? 
If that was possible the macro should be running smoothly afterwards.

Thanks for any kind of input in advance!

edit: As the command I'm trying to run is not very common, consider the problem running a "runas" command through a macro. The runas will similarily be prompting for a password , e.g.:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

edit2:
The problem with providing the credentials every time is the following: 
The program requesting the password saves the password to login to the server after you've successfully entered it once. Meaning the next time you have to enter it is (in the best case) three months afterwards when the standard password rotation requires you to set a new password for your user account. Therefore it'd be really annoying to have to enter the password every single time just because every three months it doesn't work..

Comment: Interesting problem and worthy of attention of StackOverflowers.  Sadly I do not have a command line program that mimics behaviour.

Comment: If "shell gets stuck waiting for the user input" then there may not be a simple solution.... VBA isn't multi-threaded, so if shell `.Exec` is waiting for user input, no error has been raised, and the execution is ongoing. You can't "break" in to that thread and use a `FindWindow` or other API call to manipupate the CMD window, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to simply provide the credentials to the `Shell.Execute` (i.e., assume the user must *always* enter credentials) to avoid this scenario/problem? That is how I would try to handle it, I think.

Comment: You could also try passing one of the [AppWinStyle arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x91s3x5x(v=vs.90).aspx) to the `Exec` statement, in order to maximize the CMD window so that it will be immediately visible to the user.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214503/shell-command-bring-to-front

Comment: With some wizardry, your VBA application could also "save" the password, though that wouldn't be a very secure approach. See if you can maximize the CMD window using the link(s) above, that should at least put the credential prompt right in front of the user and avoid hanging on the application.

Comment: @DavidZemens: I did use your method of just maximizing the command window with the request to put the password into the user's face. It's working fine now.
If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as the best!
Thanks everyone for your help and input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "shell gets stuck waiting for the user input" then there may not be a simple solution.... VBA isn't multi-threaded, so if shell `.Exec` is waiting for user input, no error has been raised, and the execution is ongoing. Unfortunately this means that you can't "break" in to that thread and use a `FindWindow` or other API call to manipupate the CMD window.

One approach, would be to pass one of the [`AppWinStyle` arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x91s3x5x(v=vs.90).aspx) to the Exec statement (see also: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214503/shell-command-bring-to-front) vb.net answer), in order to maximize the CMD window so that it will be immediately visible to the user irrespective of the credential check. This way, if the login fails, they'll see it and have the opportunity to respond to it.